import web3 from Web3
Anyone know how to get rid of this error when installing the web3 package using Windows? Microsoft build tools are up to date.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lru-dict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Updated build tool and Python versions. Web3 packages installed fine on Mac os
